# ML Kit crash with Dynamic Feature Module (conditional delivery)

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit, google-mlkit, dynamic-feature-module, dfm

I'm working on a feature that utilizes ML Kit Translation, and since this feature is only available for a specific country, I've moved the implementation for this feature along with ML Kit dependency to a dynamic feature module and set the delivery in the manifest to be conditional according to the user's country.

I've followed this [guide](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/tips/reduce-app-size) to move the ML Kit by adding support dependency in the base app build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:playstore-dynamic-feature-support:16.0.0-beta2'
}
```

After doing so, the application started to crash on app open if the condition is met and the feature module is included at install time, otherwise everything works fine.

Here's the log for the crash:

```
   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.mlkit.common.internal.MlKitInitProvider: com.google.firebase.components.MissingDependencyException: Unsatisfied dependency for component Component<[class com.google.android.gms.internal.mlkit_translate.zzxa]>{0, type=0, deps=[Dependency{anInterface=class com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.SharedPrefManager, type=required, injection=direct}, Dependency{anInterface=class com.google.android.gms.internal.mlkit_translate.zzwx, type=required, injection=direct}]}: class com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.SharedPrefManager

 Caused by: com.google.firebase.components.MissingDependencyException: Unsatisfied dependency for component Component<[class com.google.android.gms.internal.mlkit_translate.zzxa]>{0, type=0, deps=[Dependency{anInterface=class com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.SharedPrefManager, type=required, injection=direct}, Dependency{anInterface=class com.google.android.gms.internal.mlkit_translate.zzwx, type=required, injection=direct}]}: class com.google.mlkit.common.sdkinternal.SharedPrefManager
```

Any idea how can I fix this?

Comment: Facing same issue, please let me know if you find a solution

Comment: Was able to figure this out, here is the link to the answer with detailed steps https://stackoverflow.com/a/71378009/4291698